# I get 404 while trying to hit a resteasy service

Tags: java, tomcat7, resteasy

I have downloaded a source code and trying to access it from rest client but I am getting 404 error.
When I test the my local server, I am getting 200 OK.
What I am missing? Can any one please explain me the steps to call the service?
Here is the details of the project:

### Web.xml

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

        <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/rest</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
            </servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

### Service Class

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;



    @Path("/message")
    public class MessageRestService {

        @GET
        @Path("/{param}")
        public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

            String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

            return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The service configuration above is called using the following url:

```
GET http://{host}:{port}/rest/message/{parameter}
```

An example of this url pattern would be (remember that your hostname and port can differ depending on how you are running the example):

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/message/my+message
```

The urls above are assuming you have a web context root of `/` for your application.  You have not provided your run configuration so I cannot be sure of the context root you are using.  The context root is the base url of the application.

If you have a different context root than `/` your url will look like this:

```
GET http://{host}:{port}/{context root}/rest/message/{parameter}
```

I believe in the mykong example he is using `RESTfulExample` as the context root in his maven configuration.  This would mean that the url would be:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/message/my+message
```

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/message/mykong...
I tried with this still I am getting 404

Comment: How are you running the example?  In maven as the tutorial states or in tomcat as the tag above indicates?  If you are running in tomcat you have most likely not configured the context root correctly.